# Show Android version always on screen on android device or emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, developer-tools, android-version

I usually develop in android opening several android emulators at once, each with different android versions. If you move them on your computer it's easy to lose track of which device has which android version.

Is there any automated way to display on screen the android version by using developer options? For example, in the notifications bar, or in the wallpaper or something like that?